# Can turtle() print blank lines?

Tags: python, python-module

for eg-

```
s= turtle.Turtle()
s.fd(100)
```

Then it will print lines in the east direction by default.
The problem arises when we have to print blank lines to give some outline or to skip a part,
so how we can code using turtle module that it will print a blank line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `s.penup()` before moving to lift the pen from the paper. Use `s.pendown()` to lower the pen in order to start drawing again.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.fd) is the documentation of the turtle library where you can find more information about your turtles.